# I'm having overflow issues in this two-variable optimization program

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

First off, here is what I have so far:

```
Option Explicit

Dim y As Variant
Dim yforx As Variant
Dim yfork As Variant
Dim ynew As Variant
Dim ymin As Variant
Dim x As Variant
Dim xmin As Variant
Dim k As Variant
Dim kmin As Variant
Dim s As Variant
Dim Z As Variant
Dim Track As Variant


Sub PracticeProgram()

'Selects the right sheet
Sheets("PracticeProgram").Select

'y = k ^ 2 * (x ^ 2 + 2 * x * k - 6) / (x + k) ^ 2

'these are the bounds we are stepping through
Track = 0
x = 1
xmin = 1
k = 1
kmin = 1
y = 100000000
yforx = 100000
yfork = 1000000000

Do
    y = 100000000
    For x = 0 To 1000 Step 0.1
        ynew = kmin ^ 2 * (x ^ 2 + 2 * x * kmin - 6) / (x + kmin) ^ 2

        'This checks the new y-value against an absurdly high y-value we know is wrong. if it is less than this y-value, we keep the x-value that corresponds with it.
        If ynew < y Then
            xmin = x
            y = ynew
            yforx = y
            xmin = Application.Evaluate("=Round(" & xmin & ", 3)")
        Else
        End If

    Next
  MsgBox (yforx)


    For k = 0 To 1000 Step 0.1
        y = k ^ 2 * (xmin ^ 2 + 2 * xmin * k - 6) / (xmin + k) ^ 2
        If ynew < y Then
            kmin = k
            y = ynew
            yfork = y
            kmin = Application.Evaluate("=Round(" & kmin & ",3)")
        Else
        End If
        Next

    MsgBox (yfork)

Loop Until (Abs(yforx - yfork) < 10)

End Sub
```

This program is supposed to find the values of x and k in order to minimize the value of y. This is a practice for a much more complicated program that will use this same concept. In my actual program y, k, and x will all be greater than zero no matter what, but since it was hard to think of a simple equation whose results would be in the shape of a parabola opening up, I decided to allow negative answers for this practice program.

Basically, it should bounce back and forth between the equations finding the ideal values for x and k until finally it has a minimal answer for y using ideal answers for both x and k. I'm not sure what the actual answer is, so I'm letting it stop within a range of 10. If it works, I'll make it smaller, but I don't want the program going for forever, just in case.

**MY PROBLEM**: I keep getting overflow errors! I'm trying to round the values for xmin and kmin to three figures after the decimal, but it doesn't seem to be helping. Am I using them wrong? Can someone help me get this program working?

Comment: VBA has a `Round` function. Why are you using `Application.Evaluate`?

Comment: Because [you can't always predict how it will round when the rounding digit is a 5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa188511%28v=office.10%29.aspx). Also [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exceldev/thread/790eab38-9ba1-4e12-9f80-332f8f9c5b68/).

Comment: It's perhaps a little clearer to use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Round`

Comment: Have you considered using Solver for this?  It can be automated using VBA.

Comment: I would use the solver, but I need to evaluate this huge series using this basic idea, and I can't use the solver for that. So this is more of a proof of concept program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing a division by zero. `xmin = 0`, `k = 0`, `(xmin + k) ^ 2 = 0`. (I'm not sure why it isn't reporting division by zero.)

A suggestion: use the `Locals` pane to see the value of local variables. You can also use the `Watch` pane to see the value of expressions you want to monitor.

Comment: I got a divide by zero error when I stepped from -1000 to positive 1000. But I changed it to -100 and it went away, so I don't think that's the issue, but I could be wrong. I set the values before the do while loop in order to prevent that from happening as well.

But I think if it were a divide by zero error, it would tell me, since that is a specific error. Instead it's giving me an overflow error when I put my rounding expressions as comments, and data mismatch errors when I don't put them as comments.

I had no idea about the Locals and Watch pane! Very useful.

Comment: You may have set `xmin` before the `Do..While` but it's being changed in the first `For` loop. You have to look at the values at the second `For` loop, where the error is actually occurring. The values I listed in my post are the values at that point in the code. Setting `xmin = 1` in the `Immediate` pane allowed the code to continue.

Comment: Where do you ever step from -1000 to 10000?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that I changed it to 0 to 1000 to simplify things! So can I fix this by having it step starting at one instead of zero?

Comment: In the second `For` loop? `For k = 1 To 1000 Step 0.1`? Yes, if that's what you want to do.